# determinant annihilates ring vector

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients from $R$. Suppose for $r\in R^n$ we have $Ar=r$. Prove that $\det (A-I)\cdot r=0$.

It is actually part of a bigger problem where $r_i$ generate ring $B$ which is module finite over $R$, and we need to prove that $\mathfrak{a} B\neq B$, where $\mathfrak{a}$ is a proper ideal of $T$. (matrix entries are picked from $\mathfrak{a}$). The rest of proof is straightforward, just this fact is unclear to me.

Comment: In your first part, do you mean that $\;Ar=r\;$ *for all* $\;r\in R\;$ or just one? It looks weird since if the ring is a field, say $\;R=\Bbb R\;$ , the claim is false big time: just take $\;A=I_n\;$ . Prhaps some other data is given?

Comment: i have edited, i wrote it incorrectly, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from $(A-I_n)r=0$ by multiplying (on the left) with the [classical adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A-I_n$.

Comment: oh yes of course!